# Biholomorphic map from the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I am following a complex analysis class and in one of the exercise I have the following question:

Let $f : D_1 \rightarrow U$ be a biholomorphic map such that $f(0) = 0$. How can one check that $U$ contains a disk of radius $r$ where $r$ is at most $\vert f'(0) \vert$? In other words how can one check that $\vert f'(0) \vert \geq \operatorname{dist}(0, \partial U)$?

So far I have seen that since $f$ is biholomorphic we know that $f'(0)$ is not zero (using the chain rule). So by dividing $f$ by $f'(0)$ if necessary one can assume that $f'(0) = 1$.

I have a feeling that this might be related to Schwarz lemma but I can't really see how.

EDIT : I have found something that looks like a proof to me but in the meantime someone posted in the comments that this is not true... What is wrong with my proof?

The proof : Set $r := \operatorname{dist}(0, \partial U)$. Now consider the function $g(z) : D_1 \to D_1$ given by $g(z) = f^{-1}(rz)$. By Schwarz lemma $\vert g'(0) \vert \leq 1$ but $g'(0) = \frac{1}{f'(0)} r$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This result is not true in general. Take $f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$.It is a biholomorphic map from $D_1$ to $f(D_1)$, $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$ and $f(D_1)$ does not contain $-\frac14$, so $f(D_1)$ cannot contain a disk of radius $1$. You may be intereseted in Koebe quarter theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is your function really biholomorphic? It most certainly is holomorphic and a bijection into its image but is the inverse function holomorphic?  I ask this because in the mean time I've found a "proof" of the claim (see edit) so either my "proof" or your example is wrong (if not both ;) )

Comment: @user29339722 Your proof proves $|f'(0)|\le r=\text{dist}(0,\partial U)$, which is indeed correct. You asked for the opposite inequality (this may be a typo), which is not correct (actually one has $|f'(0)|\ge \frac14d(0,\partial U)$, by Koebe quarter theorem). My function is biholomorphic.